# iOS 17 crash collectionView at batchUpdate

Tags: ios, swift, collectionview, ios17

I am performing batchUpdate.

Here is my code:

```
if let footerIndex = self.collectionView.feeds.index(forKey: "footer") {
    self.collectionView.performBatchUpdates {
        self.collectionView.totalSections += 1
        self.collectionView.insertSections([footerIndex], animationStyle: .none)
        self.collectionView.insertItemsAtIndexPaths([IndexPath.init(row: 0, section: footerIndex)], animationStyle: .none)
    }
}
```

In all earlier iOS versions it works, but iOS 17 it crashes:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid batch updates detected: the number of sections and/or items returned by the data source before and after performing the batch updates are inconsistent with the updates.
> Data source before updates = { 47 sections with item counts: [1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1] }
> Data source after updates = { 47 sections with item counts: [1, 11, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1] }
> Updates = [
> Insert item (1 - 0),
> Insert item (1 - 1),
> Insert item (1 - 2),
> Insert item (1 - 3),
> Insert item (1 - 4),
> Insert item (1 - 5),
> Insert item (1 - 6),
> Insert item (1 - 7),
> Insert item (1 - 8),
> Insert item (1 - 9),
> Insert item (1 - 10)
> ]

This is the error. Is there any work around for iOS 17?

Comment: UICollectionView does not have methods named `insertSections(_:animationStyle:)` or `insertItemsAtIndexPaths(_:animationStyle:)`. Those seems like APIs from before Swift 3.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, the practice should be in three ways:

1. If you want to update overall collection view then you can use `collectionView.reloadData ()`
2. If you want to reload sections of collection view you can use
   `collectionView.reloadSections ()`
3. If you want to reload the specific cell of collection view you can use `collectionView.reloadItems(at: section)`

Please always use array to append/delete items and then update collectionView.